# MySql insert into query not working in PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, insert

Hi i am new to PHP and MySql and I'm facing one problem:

I am having a page that allows users to upload an image and some details like their name and their email address to my database but **the code that i have used is not working**.

In fact, **it is not adding data to my database but the image is being uploaded**.

I also want to ask that **is there any way to make all the form fields compulsory for users to fill in the form**.

The html form is as below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"><br><div align="center">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload1.php" method="POST"> 
                Your Full Name: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="40"><br> 
                Your Image Please: <input type="file" name="photo"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload!"> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code of `upload1.php`:

```
<?php 

    // random 4 digit  to add to our file name 

    // some people use date and time in stead of random digit 

    $random_digit=rand(00000000000000,99999999999999);

    //combine random digit to you file name to create new file name

    //use dot (.) to combile these two variables

    $new_file_name=$random_digit.$file_name;

    //This is the directory where images will be saved 
    $target = "g/".$new_file_name; 
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

    //This is our size condition 
    if ($photo_size > 350000) 
    { 
        echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
        $ok=0; 
    } 

    if (!($uploaded_type=="image/gif")) {
        $ok=0;
    } 
    if (!($uploaded_type=="image/jpg")) {
        $ok=0;
    } 
    if (!($uploaded_type=="image/png")) {
        $ok=0;
    } 
    if (!($uploaded_type=="image/bmp")) {
        $ok=0;
    } 
    if (!($uploaded_type=="image/jpeg")) {
        $ok=0;
    } 

    if ($ok=0) 
    { 
        Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
    } 

    else 
    { 

        //This gets all the other information from the form 
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
        $banner="/$target";
        $url="xxxxxxxxxx";
        $clicks='0';

        // Connects to your Database 
        mysql_connect("xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
        mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error()) ;


        //Writes the information to the database 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO girls (name, banner, clicks, url, email) VALUES ('{$name}','{$banner}','{$clicks}','{$url}','{$email}') "); 


        //Writes the photo to the server 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
        { 

            //Tells you if its all ok 
            echo " The file has been uploaded and renamed to '$target' your information has also been added to the database.<br>To view your image online visit www.facesnap.tk/$target ";
        } 
        else { 

            //Gives and error if its not 
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem in your upload. Be sure that you follow instructions."; 
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please use mysqli or pdo.  Mysql is no longer supported.

Comment: Try adding a semicolon to the end of your SQL statement, mySql is SQL ANSI compliant which means all SQL statements need to end with a semicolon.

Comment: What do you get when you echo out your query? Does it work when you run it straight in the database?

Comment: Should be using `mysqli` or `POD`. `msql_` functions a depecrated. Anyway I will have a look nonetheless.

Comment: put the query in its own variable `$query = "INSERT INTO girls (name, banner, clicks, url, email) VALUES ('{$name}','{$banner}','{$clicks}','{$url}','{$email}') ";` then do `mysql_query($query)`, or `echo $query` and see if everything is good with the query.

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO girls (name, banner, clicks, url, email) VALUES ('{$name}','{$banner}','{$clicks}','{$url}','{$email}') ") or die (mysql_error())` and tell us the error.

Comment: If enough comments say PDO will that help?  Please, for the love of all that is right in the world, stop now, and learn how to use PDO - this code is full of security problems - you *will* get hacked if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put '' only in varchars not in int values, if '{$clicks}' is an int in your database try remove the ''.

To make fields required now, do this in your upload1.php script:

```
    session_start();

    //connect to db

    $errors = array();

    //validate name
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Your name is required.';
    }
    else {
       $name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
    }

    //validate email
    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Your email is required.';
    }
    else {
       $email = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
       $regex = '/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/';

       //change the 128 to your email field length in your db
       if (preg_match($regex, $email) && strlen($email) <= 128) {
           $email = strtolower($email);
       }
       else {
           $errors[] = 'Your email is not valid.';
       }
    }

    //validate the file upload
    if (!isset($_FILES['photo']) || empty($_FILES['photo'])) {
         $errors[] = 'Your photo is required.';
    }
    else if ($_FILES['logo']['name'] == '') {
         $errors[] = 'Your photo is required.';
    }
    else if (!file_exists($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) {
         $errors[] = 'The file could not be uploaded, please try again later.';
    }
    else {
        //validate the extention with your function is_img_ext()
        if (is_img_ext($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
            $errors[] = 'The file you uploaded is not an image.';
        }
        //validate image size
        if ($_FILES['photo']['size'] > 350000) {
            $errors[] = 'The image you uploaded is too large.';
        }

        //if no errors and the file not exist move it to the target dir
        if (empty($errors)) {

             //generate a new filename for the image
             $random_digit=rand(00000000000000,99999999999999);
             $new_file_name = $random_digit.$file_name;
             $target = "g/".$new_file_name; 
             $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 

            echo " The file has been uploaded and renamed to '$target' your information has also been added to the database.<br>To view your image online visit www.facesnap.tk/$target ";
            } 
            else { 

            echo "Sorry, there was a problem in your upload. Be sure that you follow instructions."; 
            } 

        }
    }

    if(!empty($errors)) {
        $_SESSION['form_error'] = $errors;
        header('Location: your_form.php');
    die();
    }

    //your rest script
    .....



    function is_img_ext($filename) {
        $ext = explode('.', $filename);
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

        if ($ext == jpeg || $ext == jpg || $ext == png || $ext == gif || $ext == bmp) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In your_form.php now:

```
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['form_error'])) {
        $errors = $_SESSION['form_error'];
        unset($_SESSION['form_error']);
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    //your form here
```

Comment: I believe this will fix the problem.

Comment: The code that u gave doesnt help me. I would like to tell you that i also have one row (named as ID) in mysql that uses Primary Key, Unique & auto increament. I think due to that only my insert into not working what do u think tell?

Comment: The code that I gave you is just a simple way to check the input of the user and if he didn't submited a correct form to output the errors, else to process his input. I don't include here any interaction with the database.

Comment: About the query, try to write it like this:
"INSERT INTO girls (`name`, `banner`, `clicks`, `url`, `email`) VALUES ('$name', '$banner', $clicks, '$url', '$email')"
And don't forget to sanitise your input to prevent any sql injection. Also if you are going to output in any page this information its a good idia to use htmlentities() to prevent users to inject html and javascript in your site.

Comment: As for the ID you don't have to set it beacause it is auto_increment as you said.

Comment: I added some more checks to the code to make it more secure, you have to be careful when you take input from the user, if you make a mistake here you may have a big headache later. And if you can, NEVER use include() or require(), exept if you are very very careful, with files that have been uploaded by the user. With these functions the file extenstion is been ignored and someone can uploade a php file like this -> image.jpg and then delete your entire website or even worse steal sensitive information from your database.